# Move Emails received in the afternoon to another folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook, rules

I receive email alerts in the morning (10 am) and the afternoon (15 pm - 16 pm), (same sender, same email object).
I would like to move the afternoon alerts to a different folder through a "run a script" rule.
I tried this script but didn't work :

```
Sub MovebyTime(oItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    With oItem
        If Format(oItem.ReceivedTime, "h") >= 15 And _
           Format(oItem.ReceivedTime, "h") < 16 Then
            .Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).folders("Foldername")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Could you please specify exactly, what is the problem? Where the error/issue occurs?

Comment: Did you try to run the code under the debugger?

Comment: @TomaszPaluch the code embedded doesn't filter the emails correctly, it moves all of them to the new folder, which means the condition isn't working as expected, that's the issue

Comment: Another thing coming to my mind: the result of Format is a string. So you might have to compare "15" instead of 15 and "16" instead of 16 (or convert to lng before comparison using CLng(Format(.....))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend running the code under the debugger attached. So, you will be able to understand what is wrong with your code.

But I'd start from breaking the following line of code and declaring each property or method call on a separate line:

```
Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).folders("Foldername")
```

Compare:

```
Dim inbox as Outlook.Folder
Dim targetFolder as Outlook.Folder

Set inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set targetFolder = ns.folders("Foldername")

oItem.Move(targetFolder)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works. ns is a namespace object, whereas GetdefaultFolder returns a folder object. When testing I got a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

small update to previous answer:

```
 Set ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 set targetFolder = ns.Folders("Mailboxname").Folders("Foldername")
 oItem.Move targetFolder
```

This also covers the case where you have multiple mailboxes